# UPDATE statement: Returning into refcursor

Tags: oracle, cursor, sql-update, sql-returning

I have a query that updates a set of records based on specific criteria. I want to get columns of the result set of that update statement and pass it back in a refcursor.

I can get the result set by using `RETURNING INTO`, or in my case, `RETURNING myrows BULK COLLECT INTO ...`. However, I'm not sure how to make this work with a cursor - you can't do an `OPEN cursor FOR` with an update statement.

I'm guessing there's a way to get the results of a `RETURNING` statement into my cursor. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a SQL collection defined (rather than a PL/SQL collection), you should be able to

```
RETURNING my_column 
     BULK COLLECT INTO my_collection;
```

and then

```
OPEN p_rc
 FOR SELECT *
       FROM TABLE( my_collection );
```

Though that works, there are some caveats.  If you expect the `UPDATE` to modify a large number of rows (or you expect many sessions to be running this code), storing all this data in a collection may consume a large amount of space in the PGA which may negatively impact performance.  Reading a bunch of data into a collection just to send it all back to the SQL engine also tends to be a bit inelegant.  And, as I said initially, this assumes that your collection is declared at the SQL level rather than being declared in PL/SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! We ended up going another way with this.